# I cant figure out a way of placing my body to have at least the full screen or more if there is content?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

This probably seems like a repeat question (since I've seen 1000s of posts like this) but they all have the same answer: *"make your `html` and `body` height to `100%`/`100vh`!"* well that doesn't seem to work.

I am really a newbie in css, but I know that a height of `100%` should reference the parent, so I say that `body` and `html` have `100%` height... I ask myself: "`100%` of what?" and that is probably the error, but I've included my example to show my frustration!

I have 3 `div` in the `body`, I want the first two to be about `150px` height together, and my 3rd, I want it to be the rest of the page - even if there is no content. If the content is going larger than the window space, I want the scroll bar to appear and I want my div to be all way down while there is content!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" style="height : 100vh;" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gaming4Money</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color : red; height: 100vh;">
  <div style="background-color : yellow; height: 100px"> asd</div>
  <div style="background-color : blue; height: 50px">asd</div>
  <div style="background-color : green;  height:100%; ">asd<p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p><p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  <p>asdasd</p>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

That code is basic and I simply cannot make it go down...

This is what happens [image]

What I want: the green `div` extend to the end, somehow it is not going and when I inspect `body` it stops before the green?

[image]

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a way to do it. I recommend you to read about flexbox, it's super useful. I found this page where you can understand how it works: [Flex Box CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Gaming4Money</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style type="text/css">
      html, body {
          height: 100%;
          background-color: blue;
      }

      #wrapper {
          background-color: red;
          min-height: 100%; 
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div style="height: 150px; background-color: pink"> First Div</div>
    <div style="height: 150px; background-color: orange">Second div</div>
    <div style="background-color: green; flex: 1">Third div</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```